# Automatic strophe connect via php

Tags: javascript, php, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm currently working on user -> user chat within a PHP system. The chat works with XMPP and I've got it to successfully connect and send messages with Strophe JS. However this requires the XMPP login credentials to be entered at the client level. This is of course insecure as the credentials will be accessible from the browser. Instead I need a way of having PHP create the connection and Strophe access that without a password. Is there a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to the link  below:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/strophe/5YEVkczIZjQ

It has php backend connection way.

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes"

Answer (score 0):

I used c# and I built a class that creates/logs in the users getting the info from the database,then passes the SID, RID and JID back out to the front end (Strophe) to then attach to the jabber server to start chatting. Php shouldn't be much different. See http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html and http://metajack.im/2008/10/03/getting-attached-to-strophe/ for more.